# MySQL - how to get english and encoded characters inserted?

Tags: mysql, encoding, character-encoding

I have a multi language website which requires both English language and [Azeri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azerbaijani_language) characters to be input via a web form and inserted into a MySQL database table.

Displaying them in HTML is fine, I can work with the page encoding to get hard coded text to display. Now the site requires developing and any static text will be pulled from the MySQL.

I've tried changing the encoding of that particular table, but whatever I do it just changes all the additional characters to question marks.

Can anyone let me know how to setup a table correctly in MySQL in order to display both English and Azeri characters??

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encode data as UTF-8, it can encode virtually any language on this planet.

You just have to set the character encoding and collation correctly, AND to insert data as UTF-8. PHP (which is what you'll be using, I guess) uses latin1 by default and you might have issues with that. To get around this, use [mysql_set_charset('utf8')](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php)

Answer (score 1):

You need UTF-8 charset encoding support in MySQL. Azeri letters as Ə,Ş,Ç,Ğ,Ü and other letters will be displayed.

Comment: Where would one go to add/set this encoding support.